# the methode authenticationManager() not fond in spring securite last version

Tags: spring

In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

To assist with the transition to this new style of configuration, we have compiled a list of common use-cases and the suggested alternatives going forward
In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

To assist with the transition to this new style of configuration, we have compiled a list of common use-cases and the suggested alternatives going forward
know for spring laste version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ypsV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgnWV.png)

know for spring laste version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ypsV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgnWV.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your spring security authentication manager is deprecated.
I think this may help you

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/login").permitAll();
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .cors().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        httpSecurity.addFilterBefore("Your filter", UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity.addFilterAfter("Your filter", UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();

    }
```

`addFilter` is the choice you can use before after or both.

Comment: but when i my filter initialize by constructer using authenticateManager and the last is deprecated    ,i want to know how i can use it in the new version the spring security